# MaterialDialog form not working

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am using afollestad `MaterialDialog Library`(https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)
 and using custom view.Inside view I have five inputs and spinner. But I am trying to get values from input but not working. Also I need to populate spinner from api.

```
   MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title("Edit Paid Amount")
                .customView(R.layout.edit_payment_model, true)
                .positiveText("Update Payment").build();
Spinner spinner= (Spinner) dialog.getCustomView();
 dialog.show();
```

Can any one help me how i can achieve this ?

I have tried default alert dialog its working

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

        View dialogView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_payment_model, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
        EditText editText = (EditText)
                dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editPaymentAmount);

        editText.setText("test label");
        dialogBuilder.create().show();
```

Even i checked this issue https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/230

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with this lib, but you should find spinner/edittext view in custom view.

```
    MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .title("Edit Paid Amount")
                    .customView(R.layout.edit_payment_model, true)
                    .positiveText("Update Payment")
                    .build();

    View customView = dialog.getCustomView();
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) customView.findViewById(R.id.spinner)
    EditText editText = (EditText) customView.findViewById(R.id.editPaymentAmount);
    editText.setText("test label");
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: @Eddwhis.Thank you so much .it works like charm .Even this is not mentioned in document

Answer (score 1):

If i understand, the way to obtain the value from a View that's inside an AlertDialog

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_license, null);
builder.setView(dialogView)
.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            EditText valueView = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.license_value); //here
            if(valueView == null) Log.d("AA", "NULL");
            else{
                String value = valueView.getText().toString();
                mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(EditLicenseDialogFragment.this, value);
            }
        })
```

You are going well, but to obtain the values you must get it straight from the View that's being called.